# I mistyped a command during vagrant ssh on homestead how I can nuke everything and start over?

Tags: vagrant

When I need to run some commands eg composer I did a mistake and removed some packages such as the mysql and nginx via apt-get.

When I reinstalled them have been misconfigured therefore my app does not work as expected. So how I can nuke everything and start over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to reset averything you need to halt your machine (asuming that you `cd` into the project path where `Vagrant` is located):

```
vagrant halt
```

Then list all the vms with:

```
vagrant status
```

And purge it with the following command:

```
vagrant destroy ^vm_name^
```

Then create it again with:

```
vagrant up
```